# Opening a file from Version 2.83 in Version 2.49

Tags: versions, conversion

I am attempting to make a mod for the game Fallout New Vegas... To do that, I need to make a model in Blender, then export it as a .NIF file, but this only seems to work in version 2.49, but I have no idea how to use that version, only version 2.83... When I make something in 2.83 and attempt to open it in 2.49 so I can export it as a .NIF, I simply end up with a blank screen... Is it possible to open a file made in 2.83 in 2.49?
So far I've managed to export a file as a .OBJ and successfully open it in the older version, but it would be far easier if I could just open the .blend file itself, that way I wouldn't need to learn how to add textures and materials in the older version since in my texting, I cannot transfer textures or UVs and such if I use my current solution of transferring .OBJs

Comment: You could try exporting .FBX. It won't keep the textures, but it will keep their placements and UV maps.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.8 is not backwards compatible with previous versions.

Even if you could bring the meshes, none of the materials would work in 2.49

You might want to try using 2.79 and the internal blender render with simple materials. No nodes. Maybe those would work on 2.49